# Switch tab on click in storyboard

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboards to develop an application, i have a viewcontroller which has two buttons. I launch a tabbar controller on 1st button's click with first tab as default tab bar, now on 2nd button's click I want to launch the same tabbar controller and display 2nd tab on it.

I have tried setting the tab by using setSelectedIndex in prepareForSegue method, by giving an identifier to that segue. Help needed!

Comment: Guys found solution `' - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue )segue sender:(id)sender { if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tab1"]) ((UITabBarController)segue.destinationViewController).selectedIndex = 0; else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tab2"]) ((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController).selectedIndex = 1; } `